# Measuring Only Page Faults That Reach the Disk

Tags: windows, performance-monitoring, iops, performance-counters, pagefile

I would like to measure "truly" hard page faults, i.e. page faults that result in a disk IO.

It looks as if `Memory\Page Reads/sec` might do the trick, but as was explained in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/893565/29489), the page reads value includes reads that are satisfied from the file system cache, never reaching the disk. That seems to be the reason why the count of `Page Reads/sec` is consistently higher than the actual disk IOPS as measured by the counter `Physical Disk\Disk Reads/sec`.

**My question is:** How can I measure the number of read and write page faults per second reaching the disk?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year and no one's answered this. While I'm not expert on the subject of MS windows by any means, I believe you may want to look at `"\Memory\Pages Input/sec"` and `"\Memory\Pages Output/sec"`. Microsoft has long descriptions of these values via their PDH library. Some are described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804008.aspx). You can search that page for "hard fault", but you won't find exactly what you're looking for (only hard faults) Here's a paste of their description of "Memory\Pages Input/Sec" which *may* be of help, YMMV:

> Pages Input/sec is the rate at which pages are read from disk to
>   resolve hard page faults. Hard page faults occur when a process refers
>   to a page in virtual memory that is not in its working set or
>   elsewhere in physical memory, and must be retrieved from disk. When a
>   page is faulted, the system tries to read multiple contiguous pages
>   into memory to maximize the benefit of the read operation. Compare the
>   value of Memory\Pages Input/sec to the value of  Memory\Page
>   Reads/sec to determine the average number of pages read into memory
>   during each read operation.

An I should add, in Windows 8 and up, you can poll these values from the powershell command line with the `Get-Counter` command, e.g. `Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Pages Input/sec"`

Comment: If you want to add something, just edit your answer.